# GIT merge --no-ff

Tags: linux, git, merge, fast-forward

In this post I will someone expert on git try to explain how git merge --no-ff can help us. I have read here http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ (which I personally found to be a really good post) that git merge --no-ff: "This avoids losing information about the historical existence of a feature branch and groups together all commits that together added the feature". So I found it really useful and make some experiments.

The problem is about how can we know from the git log information which commits belong to each feature. For that I did the next experiment. Suppose two users are developing on a software project two different and independent feature (to avoid merge conflicts). From the last stable version we will proceed as this:

`git init
touch AAA.txt
git add AAA.txt 
git commit -m "My stable software version"
//this will simulate our project repository`

So from this point the two user (name Alice and Bob) create two different branches and start working on the features:

`git branch  feature1_Alice
git branch  feature2_Bob`
 
And now Alice and Bob start working and commiting simultaneously. We could simulate his as:

`git checkout feature1_Alice
touch f1_A1.txt
git add f1_A2.txt
git commit -m "Solving little bug on feature 1"`

Bob do two commits following timeline after Alice does this one:

`git checkout feature2_Bob
 touch f2_B1.txt
 git add f2_B1.txt
 git commit -m "Starting feature 2"
 touch f2_B2.txt
git add f2_B2.txt
git commit -m "feature 2: implementing new functionality"`

Then Alice finish feature:

`git checkout feature1_Alice
touch f2_A3.txt
git add f2_A3.txt
git commit -m "Feature 1 finished"`

Then Bob finishes feature2:

`git checkout feature2_Bob
touch f1_A3.txt
git add f1_A3.txt
git commit -m "Feature 2 finished"`

Now we merge the new feature to the main branch:

`git checkout master
git log`

Output:

commit c58dd35054f83c089292d090781438f37feeffa3

Author: Juan

Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:30:01 2017 +0200

```
My stable software version
```

`git merge --no-ff feature1_Alice
//We put a message on the created commit`

Now git log outputs:

commit 50c5d1570fe0c047f72200bd57ef6cef6fa9077e
Merge: c58dd35 c136a23
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:48:12 2017 +0200

```
Merging feature 1 to main
Merge branch 'feature1_Alice'
```

commit c136a23c49c546e5f48d9d0634e9bc51d67370cd
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:41:49 2017 +0200

```
Feature 1 finished
```

commit c9dbb1b49444555fca528f562d3a38143fd521e9
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:35:24 2017 +0200

```
Solving little buf on feature 1
```

commit 58afad2b46565e614a99d94d1e1aa1c8520f9f2b
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:35:01 2017 +0200

```
Starting feature 1
```

commit c58dd35054f83c089292d090781438f37feeffa3
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:30:01 2017 +0200

```
My stable software version
```

And finally merge feature 2:

`git merge --no-ff feature2_Bob
git log`

commit 3f27f78fefb30080ace629e561a242a4f8dbca56
Merge: 50c5d15 2eee0c1
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:54:20 2017 +0200

```
Merging feature 2 to master
Merge branch 'feature2_Bob'
```

commit 50c5d1570fe0c047f72200bd57ef6cef6fa9077e
Merge: c58dd35 c136a23
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:48:12 2017 +0200

```
Merging feature 1 to main
Merge branch 'feature1_Alice'
```

commit 2eee0c1bb732443ae7d6f4893d651abfd558d55a
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:43:14 2017 +0200

```
Feature 2 finished
```

commit c136a23c49c546e5f48d9d0634e9bc51d67370cd
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:41:49 2017 +0200

```
Feature 1 finished
```

commit cd3bee2906e02df22866ba710891d21eaebb8013
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:40:12 2017 +0200

```
feature 2: implementing new functionality
```

commit c6fdf092b2645f7d4088f9f439e820a9a820b891
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:37:39 2017 +0200

```
Starting feature 2
```

commit c9dbb1b49444555fca528f562d3a38143fd521e9
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:35:24 2017 +0200

```
Solving little buf on feature 1
```

commit 58afad2b46565e614a99d94d1e1aa1c8520f9f2b
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:35:01 2017 +0200

```
Starting feature 1
```

commit c58dd35054f83c089292d090781438f37feeffa3
Author: juan
Date:   Tue Apr 25 10:30:01 2017 +0200

```
My stable software version
```

Could anyone tel how can I see from the commit history and merge commit which commits influence each feature? I cannot see the advantage commented in that web when we insert alternative commits from different features (or from a feature and master) in time.

The only difference in using --no-ff is that the merge commit have information of which commits have been merged, but that is unseful for tracking the commit history.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at your repository graph with `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` or just call `gitk` to visualize your history. The linear text version provided by a simple `git log` will not show the information you're looking for.

When looking at the graph representation, merge commits ensure you can see where two branches meet, while a fast forward merge would result in different branches being shown as linear although they were developed in parallel.

Comment: Yes that was what I was looking for. Thank you.